# Is there a VBA string to select copied cells that used to have a blank formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file where everything is controlled via a macro. At one point I am moving files from one sheet to another where this data is stored as a backlog.

I then try to select blank cells and remove the row if true. But cells appear blank but are not.

So I am moving it from Sheet A to Sheet B. The data in Sheet A is being moved and pasted as values in Sheet B. The data being moved has two columns: Column A holds Item ID and column B holds a date when the item cease to exist (Cease Date).

In Sheet A, Cease Date is populated through a simple formula (=+IF(O5<>"";O5;N5)) where if there is no new Cease Date input, fetch from backlog.

Now, if there neither is no new Cease Date input nor is there any backlog, the cell is blank.

When the macro copy and paste (as values) the data from Sheet A into Sheet B, column B is populated by blank cells (as intended) but there is something invisible, for lack of better word. Almost like there would be a formatting or like when you can encounter hidden characters not seen other than by ANSI.

IF I select any of the empty cells and press delete, then run "Go to special..." and blanks, the cell gets selected by the function.

I'm using this line to remove blanks:

```
Columns("B").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

This is the segment of my code that copy/paste and handle the Cease Date section:

```
Sheets("Dashboard").Select
    Range("B3:Q400").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("CeaseDate").Select
    Range("F1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("G:T").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("F1:G1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Columns("F:G").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    Columns("B").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete 'Remove rows that does not contain a Cease Date <--- This does not work since it wont treat the blank cells as blank

'Range converting to date format

    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

    Columns("A:B").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), _
        Header:=xlYes
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
```

Comment: Do you copy and paste or cut and paste? Maybe you could post a snip of your copy pasting code. Further, if you double click on the cell and attempt to copy the characters are there any spaces or hidden characters? Can you select anything?

Comment: You can try and do a debug.print of one of the cells using ASC( e.g. 'selection.value'). This will provide you with a number if there is a character in the cell and a runtime error if nothing is present in the cell.

Comment: @MrML thank you for the input. I added the code. It is a copy/paste. I have tried to double click the cell and copy it to Notepad++ to see if there's anything, but nothing "visible".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution to this, I cannot explain *why* the problem occurs but apparently it has been something occurring in Excel since at least version 2003.

**Problem**: When I copy cells and use paste-special-value, the cells that appeared blank will fail the test of `=ISBLANK()` and returning a `FALSE` value.  Yet, there is nothing to copy from the cell or anything to mark. If I select the apparently blank cell and press delete or Backspace, `=ISBLANK()` will now return a `TRUE` value.

**Solution**:

1. I select the area with the apparently blank cells
2. Open Find/Replace function and leave the *Find What:* blank (no spaces or anything)
   and then in the *Replace With:* type in a string or word that you
   KNOW does not appear anywhere else in the spreadsheet.
3. Click *Replace All*
4. All apparently blank cells will be replaced with the word
5. Now take the word and Find/Replace it with nothing
6. The replaced cells will now be truly blank and pass the `=ISBLANK()` test

I originally found this (quite obscure) solution [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/cell-looks-blank-but-is-not/d2565b73-0c4c-41f7-b54d-38da876709a7)

Comment: Have you tried doing your `PasteSpecial` with `SkipBlanks:=True`, so that it doesn't even *try* pasting anything into those cells?  Obviously, will only work if you are pasting into an already-blank range

Comment: Testing this now!

Comment: Also tested, doesn't work.  However, `UsedRange.Columns(2).Value = UsedRange.Columns(2).Value` **will** reset the "Looks Blank" to "Is Blank" in Column B, so that `SpecialCells` can pick them up

Answer (score 1):

What you could try is also removing formatting. I have encountered this several times and it worked for me with this code. with this line all formats in blank cells are removed.

```
 Columns("B").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.ClearFormats
```

what you could also try is adding the .clearformats function to every delete part.
so if you have

```
sheet1.column("B").clearcontent
```

you could add

```
     sheet1.column("B").clearcontent
     sheet1.column("B").clearformats
```

Comment: Hi Jordi, Thanks for the input. I tried the clearformats on the whole column and it didn't work unfortunately. It did clear the formatting, which was expected, but didn't allow me to target the "blank" cells.

Comment: @RobinWiman Please note:  VBA does not count a cell with the formula `=""` as "Blank" for Special Cells, even if the Excel `COUNTBLANK` does - it has a Formula, so it's not Blank no matter what the Value is.  You would have to do something like loop through with `Sheet1.Column(2).Find("", LookIn:=xlValues)` to find cells with no Value

Answer (score 1):

If you have a cell that contains a formula, but the Value of that Formula is equivalent to `=""`, then it will display as Blank, and the `COUNTBLANK` function in Excel (or `WorksheetFunction.CountBlank` function in VBA) will call it Blank, but `SpecialCells(xlBlanks)` will **not** - because the `Range.Formula` property is not blank.

Here is a Function to retrieve cells with a Blank Value in a range:

```
Private Function GetNullValues(ByVal Target As Range) As Range
    Dim TestingArea As Range, TestingCell As Range
    For Each TestingArea In Target.Areas 'Loop through Areas in Target
        For Each TestingCell In TestingArea.Cells 'Loop through Cells in Area
            If TestingCell.Value = "" Then 'If Cell looks Blank
                If GetNullValues Is Nothing Then 'If first blank found
                    Set GetNullValues = TestingCell 'Start list
                Else 'If not first blank
                    Set GetNullValues = Union(GetNullValues, TestingCell) 'Add to list
                End If
            End If
    Next TestingCell, TestingArea 'This is the same as doing 2 Next lines
End Function
```

Use it like this: `Set BlankCells = GetNullValues(Sheet1.Columns(2))`

Comment: Thanks @Chronocidal . Do you think it would be possible to elaborate a bit on the code? I am quite new to VBA. So far i am just recording my macros and then editing the bits I know how to and look up stuff online. So I am not very familiar on how to adopt your solution to my code specifically.

Comment: @RobinWiman It just loops through every cell in the `Target` range, tests "does this have no value?" and - if so - adds it to the `GetNullValues` range to be returned by the function.  The "tricky" bit is that if you have a split-range (e.g. `A1:A2,C1:C2` without `B1:B2` included) then it is stored as 2 "Areas" - hence the double loop.

Comment: That's great! Thanks!